# Transfer comment upvotes to stars when moving discussion to chat

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, chat-stars

A lot of the time when reading (see: *skimming over*) comments under an answer for any caveats or additional notes, my eyes are automatically drawn to the comments which have the highest upvotes. Unless I'm mistaken, the selection algorithm SO uses to decide which comments to show prior to hitting *Show More Comments* also takes these upvotes into account.

When these comments get moved to chat, those upvotes are lost. Could we please get those votes transferred to stars?

Comment: One obstacle to this would be that not everyone who upvoted a comment has a chat account to record the star for.

Comment: But then again, not everyone who's comment gets transferred to chat has an account, but it works.

Comment: @davidism that is true.

Comment: (At least for me) stars represent something like a favorite with pertinent information for later, but comment upvotes usually symbolize agreement. There may be overlap, but I think it's different enough that converting upvotes to stars is not the right way.

Comment: Comments shouldn't be being moved to chat in the first place.  The discussion of a question belongs *with* the question.

Comment: @zwol Would you rather see it deleted altogether than moved to chat? Or do you mean that SO is a discussion forum and that comments are a core element that must be preserved even when the discussion is prolonged and/or tangential to the Q&A?

Comment: @Frank The latter.

Comment: @zwol [Bluefeet would disagree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813154/in-javascript-is-there-any-difference-between-typeof-x-y-and-typeof-x#comment49685612_30813234). This is why I prompted the question.

Comment: @Qix Many people disagree with me on this one, including AFAIK most or all of the moderators. I am right and they are wrong.

Comment: @zwol I agree with you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would make sense if we did something useful with the starred comments in these moved threads. Such as displaying them below the post.

But currently we do not.

If there is useful information in the thread, **edit the main-site post to add it**; don't depend on anyone else caring enough to read chat.

Comment: That last statement should be considered by the mods as well before migrating it to chat. The discussion [I mentioned in the above comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813154/in-javascript-is-there-any-difference-between-typeof-x-y-and-typeof-x#comment49685612_30813234) has some useful information that is now quite use*less* since nobody will care to read chat.

Comment: So edit them into the answer then... FWIW: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments/237983#237983

Comment: `are not directly relevant to the post` but the discussion was directly relevant to the post. I agree that adding the information to the post should be done but at the same time the comments weren't hurting anything. In fact, the discussion was done by the time bluefeet came in and moved it to chat, ultimately cutting off any will to participate anyway.

Comment: Perhaps the suggestion to edit would be a useful addition to the canned comment added during the move then?

Comment: I could agree with that.

Comment: While I agree with this on something like SO, I think it does have additional merit on something like an arts site or anything where good subjective questions are asked regularly.  I encounter situations regularly where comments have meandered in to discussion and the discussion does represent value, but comments are not the right place for it to continue.  Moving it to chat is a way to allow the discussion to continue without disrupting the Q/A, but losing the upvotes hurts the ability to have the discussion as all evidence of support is lost.

Comment: Stars and votes don't have the same meaning anyway, @AJHenderson. If you're expecting the conversation to continue in chat, nothing stopping anyone from starring whatever they want; if you *don't* expect that, then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Sure, but at that point the meaning has expanded to typical chat.  My point is just that stars are used on things people feel is useful or a good point.  This is the same as comments.  The one is a superset of the other.  Also, in the context of a discussion, I most often see people using both comment upvotes and stars in the same way.

Comment: If you want to preserve the meaning, then leave the comments as comments, @AJ.

Comment: That results in a wall of text in comments that is something that generally is prefered to avoid.  Even the migration comment suggests that comments is not the right place for discussion.  Perhaps an alternate approach would be to include (+19) or something like that at the beginning of a migrated comment to chat

Comment: Votes on comments have the primary effect of making those comments more visible under a post, @AJ. Moving comments to chat has the primary effect of making them *completely invisible* under the post, regardless of how many stars they have. If you want the upvoted comments to be visible, don't delete them. If you don't want them to be visible, then stop worrying about the upvotes that already weren't doing anything useful.

Comment: Sure, but don't stars serve a primary purpose of drawing attention to posts in chat?  My point is that while the comment is worthy of attention, under the question or answer isn't the proper place for that attention (unless my understanding of the intent of the scope of discussion in comments is vastly off).  As a discussion that is drifting off somewhat tangentially to the question or answer, the comment still merits attention, but not on the main site.  A comment can be important, but still be in the wrong place (because the entire discussion is in the wrong place.)

Comment: Yeah, but that only happens if folks are *in* chat, @AJHenderson. (Also, it works quite differently than comment votes - there's a time factor in addition to simply "number of stars") The nominal purpose of chat-stars is to aid in the creation of a sort of digest for folks entering a room & looking to catch up; the display, sorting, etc. is somewhat optimized for shorter thoughts in an ongoing stream; comment votes *might* turn up something useful there, but it's hardly a given - and of course doesn't matter at all unless the conversation continues.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with this feature request. **Upvoted comments in the main thread should be automatically starred in the chat upon moving the discussion to chat.**

**EXAMPLE:**

Main thread: [How to help a child accept when an activity is over](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/41903/33055)
[Comments moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129200/discussion-on-question-by-spencerg-how-to-help-a-child-accept-when-an-activity-i) - note that I manually starred in the chat the previously upvoted comments - this I suggest should be done automatically.

**Why is the feature useful?**

A good case study is Parenting Stack Exchange. In this stack, moderators often have to clean up the main thread from a large number of comments. The excessive comment discussions are often caused by many new users visiting hot network questions. See an example above. In many cases, the most useful comments (often good enough to be short answers!) should be automatically separated from the less useful comments. Stars is currently the best method to do this. I often read the comments that are moved to chat, and would appreciate the automatic starring of the most useful or the upvoted content.

Answer (score -5):

I don't agree. There are many comments I'd upvote on a question that I would not star in chat.