# Chat UI changes suggestions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accessibility

Now that chat will be used more in meta when discussions in comments go there, are there any changes to the chat user interface that could be implemented by SO to improve its usability and accessibilty?

Comment: So the mod policy is acted and not debatable ? Mind to link to something as reference for the "Now that chat will be used more in meta" ?

Comment: @Tensibai I suspect we have been presented with a *fait accompli* and so it would be prudent to make the best of it that we can. Not that that is the only reason to seek improvements to chat.

Comment: Fair point, I hope there'll be any improvement from this then.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [SE chat is completely inaccessible to keyboard-only users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318866/294691)

Answer (score 8):

### [Allow image uploading from the mobile site!!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276085/232439)

Especially if we'll be using it for communication about features/bugs, this will save a lot of headache for my clumsy fingers.

Comment: I upload images from mobile (iOS) all the time.

Comment: @Catija I do it from a mobile device too, but I have to request the desktop site in order to do it. It would be nice to be able to upload from the version of chat

Comment: @Catija edited to specify that I mean the mobile site. "Request desktop site -> zoom -> pan -> zoom -> repeat -> find button -> pan -> zoom -> pan -> upload" is waaaaay too many taps for what should be a simple action.

Comment: Agreed... protip: use landscape mode. ;)

Answer (score 8):

1. Allow us to vote a comment in chat.
2. While moving comments to chat, preserve the votes.
3. Allow us to move comments to already created (discussion is moved to chat) chat rooms more than once.

Latter two are not actually Chat UI changes; but related.

Comment: Don't stars on a message already hold the same purpose as upvotes on a comment?

Comment: For point one: [2012 w/dup link to 2011 request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127979/chat-should-have-distinct-upvote-and-star-features-the-right-hand-star-bo?noredirect=1&lq=1) for upvote/thumbs up & star (as favorite) feature.

Comment: For point two: [2015 SO request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297096/transfer-comment-upvotes-to-stars-when-moving-discussion-to-chat) & [2015 Meta.SE requrest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259469/transfer-upvotes-on-comments-to-stars-in-chat) & [2018 request related only to "upvotes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310239/when-moving-comments-to-chat-retain-comment-upvotes-as-chat-upvotes-not-stars?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: For 3: [the 2012 SE response, see comments for 2014 updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119692/297125) (there are none but people kept asking about it until then. Also, no feature request currently for it specifically that I know of/can find (probably because its a mod tool and the mods just asked directly)

Comment: You can already vote on comments in chat as scohe001 said: star a message. It's also more versatile because you can star/unstar (upvote/unupvote) a message an unlimited number of times; there's no time lock on how long or edit lock on when you can star/unstar.

Comment: Can messages on a post be moved to a new chat room more than once? If so, and you already have an existing room, it would be possible to move new comments to a new chat room, then move the created chat messages from that room into the chat room which was already existing. That would effectively give you #3.

Comment: @Makyen - Currently they cannot be moved more than once, at least through the GUI. I believe someone has hacked together something that directly makes the calls that allows you to do it more than once, but that's... not exactly available to most people.

Answer (score 6):

## Increase the contrast of the text against its background.

This will make it easier to read (an accessibility concern).

Also, the white-on-orange buttons at the very top are not very visible but have important functions. Some increase of their contrast against the background and of their contained text would be helpful.

---

To aid in website development, some browsers (or at least Firefox) offer accessibility checks in their developer tools: perhaps they could be used when considering colours. (Almost every text element in chat "Does not meet the WCAG standards for accessible text.")

---

A financial reason to comply with WCAG guidelines: I notice that there is no "Accessibility statement" for SO affirming their commitment to implementing accessibility best practices; customers outside the USA who might wish to purchase services from the company could be prohibited from doing so because of this.

Comment: There are quite in-depth extensions for both firefox and chrome that implement a dark mode, with additional features, specifically for chat.

Comment: @KevinB What would I have had to search for to discover that, please?

Comment: "SO Dark Chat +" is the name in chrome, i expect the firefox one to be the same (it's a port of the chrome one, with a few added features iirc)

Comment: @KevinB Thanks. The name is [SO Dark Chat Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/so-dark-chat-plus/) for Firefox users. Strangely, there is still something that makes it uncomfortable for me to read, even magnified, perhaps it's Verdana.

Answer (score 4):

Show an embedded view of chat below the post.

I think a large part of why chat is where comments go to die is that because you need to follow a link to a separate page it becomes far less visible.  A compact view of the chat with maybe 10-15 lines of text and a scroll bar to see the rest would significantly reduce the visibility problem that anything shunted into chat suffers from.

Answer (score -5):

## Make it threaded.

For example, in the fashion of Reddit.

<sub>(But not like MSDN where nested comments end up in a column of about 30 characters width.)</sub>

If you go to [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), it would be so much easier (IMHO) to see what each post is referring to if they were in a tree structure. The same can be said for discussions in comments.

This would also make it easier to encompass the initial view of an entire chat on one page.

Comment: No. It's not a forum, it's chat.

Comment: @Cerbrus In that case, is the traditional chat format unsuitable for the purpose that the entity named chat here is used for? It has been found that comments are not suitable, and their format is linear like chat.

Comment: Yes and no. I don't really see the need for threading, especially since you can reply to specific chat messages. That said, I'm strongly of the opinion that comments are deleted or moved way too easily.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, you can reply to a specific message, but that reply becomes intertwined with all the other messages. Give it a gap of a page's worth of other messages, and how easy is it to follow the thread of that conversation? Unless there's some setting in chat that I haven't found that separates it out (like threading would).

Comment: If there's a page wort of other messages, is there really a point in replying to that earlier chat message? If so, wouldn't it be better to create a room for that specific discussion?

Comment: Why not something similar to Slack?

Comment: I've been using chat for... a long time. I can't see how making it threaded would make anything more clear, because if it were, and you replied to something from an hour ago... that... "thread" wouldn't be in the active portion of the room, it'd be in the past assuming the room was decently active. It's not reddit, you aren't presented with the entire transcript at once for you to scroll through/expand.

Comment: like, slack's rooms? we have that, rooms.

Comment: @Cerbrus If there are points A, B, and C to be addressed from a post, and each of those posts generates ideas 1, 2, and 3, the explosion in chat rooms would do a good job of hiding the whole lot. (I think the comments being deleted too easily discussion has been quashed already, by SO policy.)

Comment: If it's too distracting for multiple conversations to be happening at once, it's trivial to make a new room.

Comment: @AndrewMorton nobody finds chatrooms about questions or answers from the chat interface, any way.

Comment: @KevinB the topic is threading. Slack has a single-level nesting feature. I don't see much of a use for multi-level threading, but I see some cases where single-level threading can be useful, especially for separating topics in a busy chatroom

Comment: But look at us having a constructive discussion here, and it's not even in chat!

Comment: iunno. i think i'd find that annoying, having a conversation happening half a page up from where the active chat is happening

Comment: @KevinB I had the impression that comments on meta can be a problem because there are a lot of them on *some* posts, with *some* leading down unproductive avenues complaining about new SO implementation details. If those paths could be isolated in their own threads, then people who don't want to go there could easily not expand that thread, or have it deleted. Most meta posts don't have that problem, but some problems must be dealt with.

Comment: This is why I avoid SO 'chat'. It's annoying trying to follow a conversation, if you can even call it that. It's more like a group of people tossing ideas out in the wind with no structure. That's not a conversation, that's a group of people just standing around making noise. Kinda like these comments...

Comment: If someone could pin down where the SO CEO said he thinks chat is stupid in a Stack Exchange podcast a couple of years ago [ed: approximately 2016] [from the comments here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364462/1115360), that might bolster this answer.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Not that old, but look here from 28:15 when asked about adding chat for teams: "I don't know if we're gonna add the chat rooms, we do - believe it or not - have chat rooms that are weird and we cannot get rid of"

Comment: @AndrewMorton When a message is a reply, on the left of the post, there is a up and left-turn arrow indicating it's a reply. In the main chat, if you hover over a reply, then the message which it is replying to is highlighted. If you hover over the message which is being replied to, then the reply is highlighted. If you click on the up and left-turn arrow which indicates it's a reply, then you are taken to the message to which it's replying, even if the message being replied to is not even close to where the reply is, or even if the replied-to message has been moved to another chat room.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "*If you go to SOCVR, it would be so much easier (IMHO) to see what each post is referring to*"? As Makyne has mentioned already, chat *replies* using the *reply* function already link comments via highlighting on hover, and anchor linking on click of the associated arrow at the beginning of a *reply* message.

Comment: I actually really like this idea.

Comment: @TylerH If there are, say, three or four conversations going on at the same time, why have them presented in a linear fashion?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Also, regarding Joel mentioning the stupidity of chat, the earliest reference I can find to that was my comment on March 26th, 2015: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=22323852#22323852. So I would probably work through podcasts from that date back to find where Joel mentioned it.

Comment: Funnily enough, Joel himself mentions something I and others have mentioned several times about the ask question wizard; "put the title at the bottom, after the question" at about 15:50 here https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/03/25/podcast-63-the-plumbers-up-to-67-coins/ (not relevant to this thread, but I'm going through trying to find where Joel mentioned chat and I found that gem. A good example of a good idea from the CEO that he had the opportunity to push and ...never did, even after the community asked for it.